# How can I sort a tableView according to date ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a reminder app which stores a value of the date and time. How can I sort the `tableView` cells according to the date ? 
My cells have date like the following `2017-04-11 09:37:00 +0000`

Comment: Is the date `String`, convert it to `Date`, then sort it. If it's already `Date`, skip step #1.

Comment: @vadian it was `String` I've converted it to `Date` but how do I compare all the data entries ?

Comment: Just `sort{ date1 < date2 }`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an unsorted array of dates, from which you take your data for the tableView.

It is quite simple, just sort the array and reload the tableView, like so:

```
var dates = [...] // your dates here
dates = dates.sorted{ $0 < $1 }
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

I cannot test it right now, but I think that `dates = dates.sorted{ $0 < $1 }` is equivalent to `dates = dates.sorted()`. This method sorts the dates in "ascending" order. If you want them to be arranged in descending order, you can use:

```
dates = dates.sorted{ $1 < $0 }
```

**or**

```
dates = (dates.sorted{ $0 < $1 }).reversed()
```

Comment: what do I put in the `var dates = ` ?

Comment: Your dates, of course! The Strings converted to dates @S.Verma

Comment: okay, so its from my dataBase, `task.time` and where do I sort and reload my `tableView` cells ? in my `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: When the view loads!